# Python MySQL Connector fetchone not returning dict

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have a table of users that I want to display in a flask app. I've been trying to get the values to print out in the console but I can't seem to figure out how to do that using the key (i.e. the field name). I have the following:

```
cur = CONN.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
users = cur.fetchone()

print(users)
```

Output is:

```
(1, 0, 'James', 'Brubacker', 'Anaheim', 1)
```

When I do:

```
print(users['first_name'])
```

I get:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I was under the assumption that fetchone() returned a dict by default but it doesn't. How can I get it to return a dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `fetchone` by default returns a tuple. That's a part of the dbAPI standard. You can say `cur = CONN.cursor(dictionary=True)`, as described in the fine documentation.

Answer (score 1):

fetchone() and fetchall() return tuple not the dicts by default. To access the data in tuple, you should use index if you want to retrieve the first element then do `row[0]` and you can access via `users['first_name']`.

If you need to get the result as dict, make use of any one of following option,

**Option1**

Add the parameter cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor at the end of your MySQLdb.connect.

*Sample*

```
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="host",
                        user="username",
                        passwd="password",
                        db="databasename", 
                        cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
```

**Option 2**

Update connection to return the dict

*Sample*

```
 cur = CONN.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    users = cur.fetchone()
    print(users['first_name'])
```